# Firestore Documents Template

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a Firestore Database that has a "devices" collection then each device has its own document. I already have a device with various fields.
Is there any way I can create a template where the document fields remains the same for all documents and I can just fill in the values upon adding a new device from the Firebase console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents in Firestore only contain exactly what you put in there.  There are no "default" or "understood" fields.  If you want a document field to contain some value, you will have to write it into each document.